# gets() and buffer in C

Tags: c, string, gets

I know, that using gets() is a very bad idea as it may lead to buffer overflow. But I have some queries.

Suppose a c program has the following code-

```
    char word[6];
    gets(word);
    puts(word);
```

If I input for example -
`HELLO WORLD`, is it correct to assume that `gets()` reads it as `[H] [E] [L] [L] [O] [ ]`, and the rest goes into the input buffer ?

If that happens than, how does `puts()` get the data to display the complete string ?

Comment: `gets` is a deprecated function (and was removed from the language officially)  and should not be used.

Comment: No, your assumption is incorrect, this situation is exactly where a buffer overflow happens.

Comment: Not correct to assume. `gets` do not know the buffers length so it will try to put W into an invalid memory location.

Comment: What is "the input buffer"?  As far as I can tell, the input buffer is `word`, which has space for 6 bytes.  `gets` is trying to write more than 6 bytes to it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Comment: How would `gets` know the size of the buffer?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `gets()` uses [esp()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasensory_perception) to determine the buffer length 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question suggests you think `gets` might somehow know that `word` is only 6 characters long, so it fills it with just 6 characters and leaves the rest in the buffer associated with the input stream. That is not the case. The call `gets(word)` passes **only** the start address of `word` to `gets`. That is all it receives—a starting location. It does not receive any information about length. `gets` reads from the input stream until a new-line character is read or an end-of-file is encountered or an error occurs.

If you entered “HELLO WORLD”, and the program printed that, it is because `gets` read the data and wrote it into memory, exceeding the bounds of `word`. There is not any fancy buffering or interaction occurring—gets just wrote over memory that was not assigned for that purpose. It could have broken something in your program. But it appears you got “lucky” in that the error did not immediately break your program, and the data sat there until `puts` could read it from memory and write it to output.

However, you should never expect that behavior. One reason that worked the way it did is you have a very simple program that did not do anything else with memory. In more complicated programs, where there are many objects and activities, it is more likely that overrunning a buffer will break the program in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 3):

> is it correct to assume that gets() reads it as [H] [E] [L] [L] [O] [ ], and the rest goes into the input buffer ?

No.  It is *undefined behavior* to attempt to overfill the buffer `word[]`.  Anything may happen.  Rest of code is irrelevant.  Nothing is specified about the contents of the buffer when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact problem with `gets`; it *will not* stop once it reads 6 characters, it will keep reading until it sees a newline character and assign those characters to the memory immediately following the end of the `word` buffer.  This is what a buffer overflow *is*.  If there isn't anything *important* for several bytes after the `word` buffer (like the return address for the stack frame, or another local variable), then overwriting that memory doesn't cause *obvious* problems, and `puts` will do pretty much the same thing - read from `word` *and the memory following it* until it sees the string terminator.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct to assume it just stops when it runs out space; it doesn't know how much space is available. `gets` just keeps reading in characters and writing into neighboring memory, invoking undefined behavior. You may get lucky, and that neighboring memory isn't used (before or after the `gets`), and `puts` "just works". Or it may overwrite your stack pointer, and everything explodes. Or it may write the buffer correctly, but bits of the buffer get overwritten before `puts` gets there. Or anything else; it's undefined behavior.

Don't do this. Never use `gets`.

Answer (score 2):

The `gets` function reads a full line at a time.  So in your example it would attempt to read "HELLO WORLD" which is 11 characters into a buffer that is only 6 characters wide.  This overflows the buffer causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And because `gets` has no way to limit how many characters it can read, this makes it dangerous which is why it was removed from the C11 standard.